# Python3.5 -configure a single cell to expand instead of the entire row or column

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

Picture a 4x4 grid in a tkinter window. I want to expand the cell at row 2, column 2 but not everything else on row 2 or column 2. Im designing a text window with selectable options on the left side in rows 1-15. Making row 2 with weight 1 and column 2 with weight 1 allows my Text widget to expand but so does everything else in row 2 and column 2. Any way around this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


lbl1 = Label(root, text="label1")
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)

lbl2 = Label(root, text="label2")
lbl2.grid(row=1, column=0)

lbl3 = Label(root, text="label3")
lbl3.grid(row=3, column=0)

lbl4 = Label(root, text="label4")
lbl4.grid(row=5, column=0)

txt = Text(root, state='disabled', bg='#E8E8E8')
txt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=2,      rowspan=2)


root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Example 2:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)
frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)


lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="label1")
lbl2 = Label(frame2, text="label2")
lbl3 = Label(frame2, text="label3")
lbl4 = Label(frame2, text="label4")

lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
lbl2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)
lbl3.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N)
lbl4.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=N)

txt = Text(frame3, state='disabled', bg='#E8E8E8')
txt.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=2, rowspan=2)


root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame3.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame3.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Example 2 has everything in the position I want it in but the Text widget does not expand. Is it possible to set a frame to expand when using grid?

Comment: I think without a concrete example this is going to be hard to answer. There _is_ an answer, but the right answer depends on many variables.For example, assuming you want it to expand to the right, what do you expect to happen to the widgets on the right in the same row? Do they shift over? Get overwritten? Same thing for expanding vertically -- what happens to items in the rows underneath? How much expansion can happen? Can the item in row 2 column 2 double in size? triple? Can it fill the whole screen? can it disappear completely? Do you have the ability to change the UI?

Comment: Example added above. I want only the Text widget to expand when the windows is maximized or a user drags the corner of the window. I want the labels 2-4 to be in the top left next to each other and not separated. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks about a 4x4 grid, but your example shows only two columns. That makes it hard to understand what you want. In the comments you say you simply want the text area of the example to grow and shrink and all the labels together, so that's what I'll address.

The simplest solution is to have an extra row and column to the right and below the text area. Have the text widget span into those areas, and give those areas a weight of 1. That means that, as the window changes size, any extra space is allocated to areas not occupied by buttons.

pro tip: I find layout problems much easier to visualize and solve when all of the layout code is together.

It would look something like this:

```
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
lbl2.grid(row=1, column=0)
lbl3.grid(row=2, column=0)
lbl4.grid(row=3, column=0)
txt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=2, rowspan=4)

root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

---

I think your layout problems might be better solved by using `pack` instead of `grid` for part of the layout. For example, you might start with three areas: a toolbar, a side panel, and then main area with the text widget:

```
toolbar = Frame(root, ...)
side = Frame(root, ...)
main = Frame(root, ...)

toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
side.pack(side="left", fill="y")
main.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

With that you now have three relatively independent areas. You can use `pack` or `grid` in each of these frames independently, making it much easier to keep track of rows and columns.

Comment: I didn't realize I could mix pack and grid like that. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Also, putting the grid configuration for everything in one section does make it easier to manage. Thanks for that.

Comment: @sidnical: you can mix grid and pack in an application,  you just can't use both for widgets that have the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

One way around it would be to make your grid twice as large, setting the things you want to be expandable to span two columns/rows.

I.e. you use exclusively odd numbered rows/columns for `grid`ing things ([1,1][1,3],[3,1][3,3]...) and you set even-numbered rows/columns to have weight. Anything you want to expand in one or both directions gets a `columnspan` or `rowspan` of 2, pushing it into a row/column which may expand as needed.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.

Comment: This does not work. If I put the tools on 0, 2, 3, 4, etc and leave row 1 blank aside from my Text widget on row 1. Then do the same with my columns and and have only my Text widget on column 1. When I change the size of the tkinter window column 1 and row 1 are expanded which allows the Text widget to expand but also pushes the other tools on rows 2+ down and row 1 becomes this giant gap. If I could adjust frames instead of only windows I would do that but it doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you actually specify the `rowspan` and `columnspan` arguments for the `grid` on your `Text`?

Comment: add sample code above. This shows how it throws the rest of the labels below the Text widget and expanding drags them down as the widget expands.  I want label 3 and 4 to stay up with label 2 and not move. Placing the widget on a row below the labels puts a big gap above the widget and I dont think we have a way to span rows backwards. Delioth, if I didn't format as you were recommending please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

With the information everyone has provided I was able to come up with a solution. I left the Text widget on the main window instead of in a frame and put my labels/tools in frames. Basically using the fact that a frame will not expand to lock down the labels. Now when the window is expanded only the widget grows.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=1)
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)


lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="label1")
lbl2 = Label(frame2, text="label2")
lbl3 = Label(frame2, text="label3")
lbl4 = Label(frame2, text="label4")

lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
lbl2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)
lbl3.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N)
lbl4.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=N)

txt = Text(root, state='disabled', bg='#E8E8E8')
txt.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW", columnspan=2, rowspan=2)


root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for all the help.